# TypeScript definition where property type is known but the name is *not*

Tags: kendo-ui, typescript

So I'm working to convert parts of the Kendo UI library to TypeScript, but I'm stuck on the Model class. The problem is the way the Fields are specified.

Given the following array:

```
 function someModelFields() {
    return {
        Id: { editable: false, nullable: false, defaultValue: emptyGuid },
        ScenarioId: { editable: false, nullable: false, defaultValue: emptyGuid },
        UnitId: { editable: false, nullable: false },
        UnitNumber: { type: "string", editable: false },
        SquareFootage: { type: "number", editable: false }
    };
};
```

...how would I model this in TypeScript, where the property name could be anything, but the type for the property is known? Here is what I have so far:

```
export module Kendo {

    export module Data {

        export class FieldTypeEnum {
            static string: string;
            static number: string;
            static boolean: string;
            static date: string;
        }

        export class ValidationDefinition {
            required: bool;
        }

        export class FieldDefinition {
            defaultValue: string;
            editable: bool;
            nullable: bool;
            parse: () => any;
            type: FieldTypeEnum;
            validation: ValidationDefinition;
        }

        export class ModelDefinition {
            id: string;
            fields: any[];
        }
```

I know the definition for "fields" is wrong, and I know I'm missing a type in between ModelDefinition.fields and the dynamic propertyname of type FieldDefinition.

Ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't really a way to model this in TypeScript beyond what you already have.